# How can I force Firefox to always use Tahoma instead of Arial?

Tags: windows, fonts

How can I force Firefox to always use Tahoma instead of Arial under Windows 7? I would be sitisfied even if to substitute Tahoma for Arial systemwide as well. I am fed up not being able to distinguish  I and l (`I` and `l`) on the websites.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain the downvote?

Comment: Well, I'm tempted to downvote too... Your question states firefox, and now it's about the entire system. Your question also reads in the 1st line you want to use only Tahoma, where in the second line you state you want to substitute Tahoma for Arial. Making Arial system wide will not resolve the issue of not distinguishing the different characters

Comment: I'd say the down votes are from this being a poorly written question which sounds more like a complaint. There is no indication of your research or description of what you've tried so far. Adding those details would be an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question.

If you mean to change the font for each website (to override their chosen font), then you can use [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) to apply a custom style... This naturally has the potential to render pages incorrectly...

```
body, td, input, textarea, select, a, h, span, div {
font-size: 8pt !important;
font-family: Tahoma !important;
}
```

It also suggests you could try replacing ONLY Arial with Tahoma

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Comic Sans to Segoe font
// @namespace     for bb
// @include     *
// ==/UserScript==

var elementList = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var i = elementList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var elementItem = elementList[i];
        var style = getComputedStyle(elementItem, '');
                elementItem.style.fontFamily = style.fontFamily.replace(/Comic Sans MS/i, 'segoe');

}
```

[Source for CSS from](http://forums.stardock.com/420495)

If you mean the font used by FireFox, then:

```
Changing Font

To change the font:

    Click the menu button New Fx Menu and choose Options
    Select the Content panel.
    Under Fonts & Colors, use the drop-down menus to select the font and font size of your choice.

    font.png

    Click OK to close the Options window 

Custom Fonts

Some websites have custom fonts, to disable them:

    Click the menu button New Fx Menu and choose Options
    Select the Content panel.
    Under Fonts & Colors, click the Advanced... button.

    advance.png

    In the window that opens uncheck the box next to Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of my selections above.

    custom_font.png

    Click OK to close the Fonts window.
    Click OK to close the Options window
```

[Source](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-fonts-and-colors-websites-use)

Comment: Is there a way to change Arial to Tahoma systemwide?

Comment: How to modify the second script for Tahoma and Arial?

Comment: so to substitute Tahoma for Arial everywhere.

Comment: everywhere in the system.

Comment: also I do not see how to add a custom scrfipt to GreaseMonkey. It just suggests to download.